# How does one hide or show a form input, based on the value of another input?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

How can I dynamically hide an input field that is built using Rails form helpers?  For example, consider the following code:

```
    <%= f.select :notification_type, [['Specific','Specific'],['Mass','Mass'],['All','All']] %>

    <%= f.label 'Enter the specific customer imei whom you want to send' %>
    <%= f.text_area  :imei %>
```

How would I hide or show the `imei` text area based on the value of `notification_type`?

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. What have you tried already? If you want this behavior to be "dynamic" you might want to look into handling it with Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use JS/jQuery if you want this to happen without refreshing the page. First set your form like so:

```
<%= f.select :notification_type, [['Specific','Specific'],['Mass','Mass'],['All','All']], class: "notification-type" %>
<%= f.label 'Enter the specific customer imei whom you want to send' %>
<%= f.text_area  :imei, class: "imei", display: none %>
```

Then add some jQuery (CoffeeScript in this example) either in your assets/javascript or your views/action_name.coffee.erb like so:

```
$->
  $(".notification-type").on "select", ->
    if $(this).val() == "Mass" # replace the condition with the thing that should show the text area
      $(".imei").show()
    else
      $(".imei").hide()
```

Something like this should work.. though you'll probably need to play with it as I haven't tested this code.

Comment: <script type="text/coffeescript">
$->
  $(".notification-type").on "select", ->
    if $(this).val() == "Mass" 
      $(".imei").hide()
    else
      $(".imei").show()
</script>     i included this in my html.erb but nothing happened :(

Comment: Do you have an app/assets/javascript/application.js (or application.coffee) file?

Comment: yes i have  it can u exactly tell me what do i have to do there and how to integrate it with my view

Comment: Create a new file called `app/assets/javascript/notifications.coffee` and paste my code in there. Restart your rails server and try now.

Comment: If still nothing works, below the `$->` line add: `alert("It works")`. You must indent as white-space matters in coffeescript. Now refresh your browser... you should get an alert. Let me know.

Comment: getting the alert but rest of it doesnt work dude :(